# How can I boot Linux in HP Pavillion x360?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, hp

I recently installed *Manjaro* on my *Windows 10 HP Pavillion x360*. Everything went fine until I had to reboot. I hoped to find **GRUB** but...surprise! it booted into Windows.

After that I rebooted into *Manjaro* through *Windows*, and checking with `efibootmgr` I realized that the boot order was wrong, so I changed it and rebooted, and.. it still booted into Windows. Repeated the same operation, but then I erased the Windows EFI entry and... still booted into Windows! I couldn't find any elegant way to boot into my new Linux system.

In the end I managed to boot, but I had to use a very "shady" solution: I changed the location of my grub.efi to /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ and changed its name to the windows .efi, then I renamed the Microsoft folder to Microsoftt (so the BIOS wouldnt recognize it as the *Windows* bootloader and recognized my **GRUB** instead) and changed the Windows entry in **GRUB**.

It works, but its way far from optimal, also, every time I update I loose the Windows entry because **GRUB** fails to recognize it, so I have to add it manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering so quickly. I will use paragraphs, sorry about that :) The thing is that the BIOS doesnt let you choose which EFI to boot, it defaults to Windows every time(editing with efibootmgr should be the same as to change the order in the BIOS)